# Can't delete folder. Infinitely looped folders created within each other

Tags: windows

My flex builder somehow decided to create infinite folders within folders and crashed itself. Now windows cannot delete the folder, saying the file name is too long. Even Unlocker can't delete it.

The folders are created like this:

```
projectname-debug -> projectname-debug -> projectname-debug -> ..........
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting it while running Windows in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boot up some linux [live distribution](http://linuxmint.com/) and delete it from there.

Comment: Then stay in linux.

Comment: And what if he's programming in Visual Studio?

Comment: I never said it was practical. ;)

Comment: @Ivo: then use WINE...

Comment: @Ivo: I'm using Flex Builder 3, an Eclipse plugin
@Josh: Bingo... did just that. I happened to have Ubuntu installed. Cheers mate!

Comment: Soo did it work?

Comment: I just wrote an article on Flex development in Linux, but it won't be published for a while yet.  However, see http://unlikelyteacher.com/2008/09/26/free-alternative-to-flex-builder/ and http://axdt.org/, which should work under Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using the [SUBST](http://www.computerhope.com/substhlp.htm) to map a long path to a new drive letter. That may get the path down short enough for you to delete some of the lower directories first.

Comment: Nice! That works great. In fact, it gave me the idea of renaming the parent directory/directories to shorter names which also works.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command line:

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\path\to\folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue due to a screwed up subversion checkout. What I found worked was going in as deep as you can and the move the contents out. You should then be able to delete the outer part. Repeat the process with the stuff you moved out. Worked for me, but it might not be exactly the same situation.

Comment: Windows will stop traversing inside the folders after a while. I used `rm /s` and it removed all the contents inside the folders, but the folders itself won't go away.