# Duplicated Junction Folder

Tags: windows-7, backup, junction

Using Cobian Backup, I backed up my home folder and neglected to deselect "Include Junctions." I now have a recursive Application Data folder filling my entire backup drive:
`B:\Desktop\TIMOTH~1\AppData\Local\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\Application Data...`

Is there an easy way to remedy this, or do I need to bite the bullet and format the drive?

Comment: Just curious- Is your backup destination a 3.5-inch floppy disk? i don't think I've seen a B: drive since MS-DOS 6 days.

Comment: 2TB HDD. B: for backup. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a folder which is nested quite deep and avoid “File name too long”?](http://superuser.com/q/256105/289138), [Tool for deleting directories with path/names too long for normal delete](http://superuser.com/q/78434/289138), [Can't delete folder. Infinitely looped folders created within each other](http://superuser.com/q/103433/289138)

Comment: and31415 is correct. Sorry, I didn't think to search for that because I assumed the junction points would make a difference. Question is answered.

Comment: Didn't work. The junctions broke it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete a symbolic link?](http://superuser.com/questions/167076/how-can-i-delete-a-symbolic-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to format the drive. The junctions were not removed by deleting the attached folders. One possible other option: [How can I delete a symbolic link?](https://superuser.com/questions/167076/how-can-i-delete-a-symbolic-link)